# How do you get overflow auto working with css grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the code snippet below the left column "accordion" should be scroll-able on overflow but not the whole page.  Currently it looks like the whole page is scroll-able even though I just want the accordion to overflow.

The content page should overflow if needed but no the whole page

```css
/*Page Layout*/

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: [col] 225px [col] 1fr  ;
  grid-template-rows: [row] 1fr;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.content{
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: row 1 ;

}
.myaccordion{;
  grid-row: row 1 ;
  grid-column: 1;
  background-color:  #da516e;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}




/*IGNORE BELOW HERE AS THIS IS FOR ACCORDION ONLY*/

/* *********************************************************************************************

How to Create CSS3 + jQuery Accordion Menu [Tutorial]
"How to Create CSS3 + jQuery Accordion Menu" that was specially made for DesignModo by our friend Valeriu Timbuc. 

Links:
http://vtimbuc.net/
https://twitter.com/vtimbuc
http://designmodo.com/futurico
http://vladimirkudinov.com
http://rockablethemes.com

********************************************************************************************* */

/* Reset */

.accordion,
.accordion ul,
.accordion li,
.accordion a,
.accordion span {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
}

.accordion li {
 list-style: none;
}

/* Layout & Style */

.accordion li > a {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 min-width: 110px;
 padding: 0 10px 0 40px;
 height: 32px;

 color: #fdfdfd;
 font: bold 12px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .35);

 background: #6c6e74;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%, #4b4d51 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6c6e74), color-stop(100%,#4b4d51));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  #6c6e74 0%,#4b4d51 100%);

 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.accordion > li:hover > a,
.accordion > li:target > a,
.accordion > li > a.active {
 color: #3e5706;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
 
 /*background: url(../img/active.png) repeat-x;*/
 background: #a5cd4e;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%, #6b8f1a 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a5cd4e), color-stop(100%,#6b8f1a));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%); 
}

.accordion li > a span {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 7px;
 right: 0;
 padding: 0 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 
 font: normal bold 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
 background: #404247;
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 border-radius: 15px;

 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
 box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
}

.accordion > li:hover > a span,
.accordion > li:target > a span,
.accordion > li > a.active span {
 color: #fdfdfd;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .35);
 background: #3e5706;
}

/* Images */

.accordion > li > a:before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 content: '';
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 margin: 4px 8px;

 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: url(../img/icons.png);
 background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.accordion li.files > a:before { background-position: 0px 0px; }
.accordion li.files:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.files:target > a:before,
.accordion li.files > a.active:before { background-position: 0px -24px; }

.accordion li.mail > a:before { background-position: -24px 0px; }
.accordion li.mail:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.mail:target > a:before,
.accordion li.mail > a.active:before { background-position: -24px -24px; }

.accordion li.cloud > a:before { background-position: -48px 0px; }
.accordion li.cloud:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.cloud:target > a:before,
.accordion li.cloud > a.active:before { background-position: -48px -24px; }

.accordion li.sign > a:before { background-position: -72px 0px; }
.accordion li.sign:hover > a:before,
.accordion li.sign:target > a:before,
.accordion li.sign > a.active:before { background-position: -72px -24px; }

/* Sub Menu */

.sub-menu li a {
 color: #797979;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);

 background: #e5e5e5;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9;

 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.sub-menu li:hover a { background: #efefef; }

.sub-menu li:last-child a { border: none; }

.sub-menu li > a span {
 color: #797979;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
 background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;

 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
}

.sub-menu em {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin-left: 14px;
 color: #a6a6a6;
 font: normal 10px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Functionality */

.accordion li > .sub-menu {
 display: none;
}

.accordion li:target > .sub-menu {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="accordionmenu.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="myaccordion">
  
    <ul class="accordion">

      <li id="one" class="files">

        <a href="#one">My Files<span>495</span></a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Dropbox<span>42</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Skydrive<span>87</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>FTP Server<span>366</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>04</em>Dropbox<span>1</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>05</em>Skydrive<span>10</span></a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li id="two" class="mail">

        <a href="#two">Mail<span>26</span></a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Hotmail<span>9</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Yahoo<span>14</span></a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li id="three" class="cloud">

        <a href="#three">Cloud<span>58</span></a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Connect<span>12</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Profiles<span>19</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>Options<span>27</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>04</em>Connect<span>12</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>05</em>Profiles<span>19</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>06</em>Options<span>27</span></a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li id="four" class="sign">

        <a href="#four">Sign Out</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Log Out</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Delete Account</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>Freeze Account</a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>
      <li id="one" class="files">

        <a href="#one">My Files<span>495</span></a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Dropbox<span>42</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Skydrive<span>87</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>FTP Server<span>366</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>04</em>Dropbox<span>1</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>05</em>Skydrive<span>10</span></a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li id="two" class="mail">

        <a href="#two">Mail<span>26</span></a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Hotmail<span>9</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Yahoo<span>14</span></a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li id="three" class="cloud">

        <a href="#three">Cloud<span>58</span></a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Connect<span>12</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Profiles<span>19</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>Options<span>27</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>04</em>Connect<span>12</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>05</em>Profiles<span>19</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>06</em>Options<span>27</span></a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li id="four" class="sign">

        <a href="#four">Sign Out</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Log Out</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Delete Account</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>Freeze Account</a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>
      <li id="one" class="files">

        <a href="#one">My Files<span>495</span></a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Dropbox<span>42</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Skydrive<span>87</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>FTP Server<span>366</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>04</em>Dropbox<span>1</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>05</em>Skydrive<span>10</span></a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li id="two" class="mail">

        <a href="#two">Mail<span>26</span></a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Hotmail<span>9</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Yahoo<span>14</span></a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li id="three" class="cloud">

        <a href="#three">Cloud<span>58</span></a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Connect<span>12</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Profiles<span>19</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>Options<span>27</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>04</em>Connect<span>12</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>05</em>Profiles<span>19</span></a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>06</em>Options<span>27</span></a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li id="four" class="sign">

        <a href="#four">Sign Out</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Log Out</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Delete Account</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>Freeze Account</a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>
      <li id="four" class="sign">

        <a href="#four">Sign Out</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Log Out</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Delete Account</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>Freeze Account</a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>
      <li id="four" class="sign">

        <a href="#four">Sign Out</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Log Out</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Delete Account</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>Freeze Account</a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>
      <li id="four" class="sign">

        <a href="#four">Sign Out</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Log Out</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Delete Account</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>Freeze Account</a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>
      <li id="four" class="sign">

        <a href="#four">Sign Out</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">

          <li><a href="#"><em>01</em>Log Out</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>02</em>Delete Account</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><em>03</em>Freeze Account</a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {

    // Store variables

    var accordion_head = $('.accordion > li > a'),
      accordion_body = $('.accordion li > .sub-menu');

    // Open the first tab on load

    accordion_head.first().addClass('active').next().slideDown('normal');

    // Click function

    accordion_head.on('click', function (event) {

      // Disable header links

      event.preventDefault();

      // Show and hide the tabs on click

      if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
        accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
        $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideToggle('normal');
        accordion_head.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }

    });

  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Updated:

The padding is on purpose as it raises the accordion from being at the bottom of the page.  Reason is that if you scroll over an item in the accordion menu the browser displays a link which can obstruct the view of of the last item in the menu.
[image]

Comment: Is `overflow: scroll` not your desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers normally give the `body` element an 8px margin by default.

So first reset that:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Second, your grid container has bottom padding which doesn't appear to be doing anything, except causing the viewport to have vertical scroll. Remove that:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: [col] 225px [col] 1fr  ;
  grid-template-rows: [row] 1fr;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  /* padding-bottom: 20px; */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3tgdydug/1/

Comment: The padding is on purpose as it raises the accordion from being at the bottom of the page.  Reason is that if you scroll over an item in the accordion menu the browser displays a link which can obstruct the view of of the last item in the menu.  See updated picture

Comment: Okay. Well that's a reason for the vertical scroll. Add it back in and factor it into the height with `box-sizing: border-box`.